# How to avoid system lock on mysql query

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Thanks for taking time to check my question.

I am trying to create a temporary table from select in mysql.
But i am facing `system lock` on query and it's on waiting for long time(~1hour).

Below is the Create statement i'm using,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ds_replication1
SELECT 
        tmp1.org_id,
        tmp1.dataobject, 
        tmp1.attribute_privacy_category,
        tmp1.pii_attribute_repln_count
FROM
        vignesh_test.pi_replic6_grp_ds tmp1 inner join dataobject_risk tmp2
ON tmp1.org_id = tmp2.org_id and
tmp1.dataobject = tmp2.dataobject;
```

And below is the explain plan on select statement.

```
# id    select_type table partitions type possible_keys key                   key_len ref rows      filtered Extra
1   SIMPLE      tmp2            ALL  idx_ORG_ID                                               219617 100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE      tmp1                 ref    idx_org_dbobj idx_org_dbobj 5   venmo.tmp2.ORG_ID   7677 100.00 Using index condition
```

Could you please help me in avoiding the system lock on this query.

Comment: Presumably you already have composite indexes on (org_id,dataobject)?

Comment: yes, i have composite index  on (org_id,dataobject) for tmp1, but index on org_id in tmp2.

Comment: The EXPLAIN suggests not

Comment: tmp1 index:
KEY `idx_org_dbobj` (`org_id`,`dataobject`)

tmp2 index:
 KEY `idx_ORG_ID` (`ORG_ID`)

Comment: Sorry, I meant for tmp2!!

Comment: @strawbeery, I just created index on (org_id, dataobject) on tmp2 also, now i can get the result. Thanks for the clue.
By the way, i ran even more huge record volume queries than this, i haven't faced system lock, why does it is going for system lock, is there any way i can avoid it.

Comment: I'm afraid that's above my pay-grade ; might be a question for the dba forum